# Why is my ASP.NET Web Page not Getting or Setting my Session Variable?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, session

I've added bits of debug code in an attempt to figure out what is going on with my Session variable, and it appears that it is always empty.

Could someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

This is probably some noobie mistake, because I don't do much web development.

```
private const string PASSWORD = "PASSWORD";

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(password)) {
    lblMessage.Text = !IsPostBack ? "Not a PostBack!" : "A PostBack.";
  } else {
    ShowData(IsPostBack);
  }
}

private string password {
  get { return Session[PASSWORD] as string; }
  set { Session[PASSWORD] = value; }
}

protected void Password_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  string val = txtPassword.Text.Trim();
  if (val == ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[PASSWORD].ConnectionString) {
    password = val;
    txtPassword.Text = null;
  } else {
    Response.Redirect(val);
  }
}

private void ShowData(bool postType) {
  // I would display my data here if it ever got to this point!
}
```

**EDIT:** When the `Password_Click` event fires, all I ever see is "Not a PostBack!" or "A PostBack." So, my Session variable must not be getting set.

Comment: does your site run on just one server, or is it hosted on multiple servers behind some sort of load balancer?

Comment: It is hosted by GoDaddy. Otherwise, I don't know how to tell.

Comment: Unless you have specifically disabled sessionstate (which I don't think you did), your code looks OK. The only thing I can think of is that your method `Password_Click`doesn't get called. Can you put a breakpoint there and see whether the variable actually gets set. If not show us the ASP.NET markup so we can see why it's not firing the event

Comment: @Kenneth if sessions were disabled he would be getting an exception.

Comment: Yes you're right, that's why I figured he didn't because he didn't mention any exceptions. However his code should work if everything is set up all right.

Comment: @Kenneth however if this condition does not happen: "val == ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[PASSWORD].ConnectionString)" he gets redirected, I guess this is what is happening.

Comment: Are you sure that ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[PASSWORD].ConnectionString comes back with the value you're expecting?

Comment: Well, that's supposing he's not entering the correct password ... Therefore I wanted to know whether the variable actually gets set. I'm quite sure it's not.

Comment: @Kenneth which I think might well be the problem, because I don't see anything else.

Comment: Kenneth, thank you for pointing out the stupid mistake. I never wired up the `Password_Click` event. I should have more confidence in Session variables and PostBacks. They have typically been my Achilles Heel.

Comment: @Kenneth: If you'd be kind enough to provide your comment up there as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: OK, I have added the answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you have specifically disabled sessionstate (which I don't think you did), your code looks OK.

The only thing I can think of is that your method `Password_Click` doesn't get called.

Please put a breakpoint there and see whether the variable actually gets set. 
If not show us the ASP.NET markup so we can see why it's not firing the event

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code, the only "issue" I see which can create this behaviour is this line:

```
Response.Redirect(val);
```

I would say that your are getting a redirect, because otherwise your code seems right to me.

Comment: Not a redirect. Kenneth was right. I had some dumb noobie error. I never wired up the `Password_Click` method. OMG.

Comment: Well this kind of thing happens to us all :)

Answer (score 1):

In this scenario the only way Session[PASSWORD] (effectively Session["PASSWORD"]) gets set is if there is an entry in your web.config:

```
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="PASSWORD" connectionString="xxx" providerName="<Some Provider>" />
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

And you type a string in txtPassword control that matches the string in connectionString attribute of the PASSWORD entry in the  section of your web.config

Comment: Actually, when `Password_Click` is fired, the string in `txtPassword.Text` is assigned to `Session[PASSWORD]` - which can be anything! Even **StackOverflow**. I simply reused an existing value in my code when writing the connection string in the `Web.config` file, so that line would look like `<add name="PASSWORD" connectionString="StackOverflow">`. I'm sure there are other/preferred ways to store the password in a config file, but I know how to use the connection string! :)

Comment: Well that was the point I was getting at :) - I assumed the connection string was just for example purposes - but you should look into **AppSettings** - same idea, but a more appropriate place than ConnectionsStrings for what your doing here.